# How do I access the parent item from a custom field in the Sitecore Content Editor?

Tags: sitecore

Normally, when I want to access the current Item in Sitecore, I go through `Sitecore.Context.Item`. This works well when creating a tool which will be used by the end user, but not for a tool which is consumed by the Sitecore admins. If I want something to show up as a custom field in the `Content Editor` itself, the `Context.Item` is a reference to the `Content Editor` and not to the node which is selected in the editor.

For the most part I can get around this by using the `ItemID` property, but if I have event dispatchers on the field, those will no longer have access to the ItemID. Eg:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsEvent)
    {
        // ItemID is defined here!
        Button live = FindControl(GetID(LiveButton)) as Button;
        if (live != null)
        {
            live.ServerProperties["Click"] = string.Format("{0}.LiveClicked", ID);
        }
    }
}

public void LiveClicked()
{
   // ItemID is blank here!
   DoSomething();
}
```

How do I gain access to ItemID in my listener (like `LiveClicked` above)?

Comment: I realize that this is not what the custom fields are really supposed to do, but the client has stated explicitly that he wants certain functionality in the main body of the Content Editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was through something called `ServerProperties` and I called the equivalent to this function in every listener.

```
private void SyncID()
{
    var live = FindControl(GetID(LiveButton)) as Button;
    if (live != null)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemID))
        {
            ItemID = live.ServerProperties["owner_id"].ToString();
        }
        live.ServerProperties["owner_id"] = ItemID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize that this is code smell. This strikes me as just plain wrong, but it solved the problem. If there is a better answer, I will gladly accept that and replace this.